# Fibered category over $\operatorname{Aff}/\Bbb A^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, vector-bundles, connections

Let $X$ is be smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Let $S$ be a scheme and let $S \xrightarrow[]{t}\Bbb A^1$ be a global function. Let $\mathcal C_S$ be the category whose objects are pairs $(\mathcal E, \nabla )$ where $\mathcal E$ is a degree zero vector bundle on $X_S = X\times S$ and $\nabla$ is a connection on $\mathcal E$, and whose morphisms are isomorphisms
commuting with the connections.

Prove that

- $\mathcal C_S$ with the "obvious" inverse image functor is a fibered catgory over the category $\operatorname{Aff}/\Bbb A^1$.

My attempt:

- I think that the obvious inverse image functor should take an object $(\mathcal E, \nabla ) \in \mathcal C_S$ as input and outputs an affine scheme over $\Bbb A^1$. The problem here is that neither $X$ nor $S$ are affine, so I thought rather about $\operatorname{Spec(\mathcal E(X\times S))} $, or even $\operatorname{Spec(\mathcal E(X))} $ but it doesn't seem right. I don't know what would be this inverse image functor?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bit ambiguously stated, but I think it should probably be interpreted so that $\mathcal C_S$ is the fiber of the fibered category over $S$, which must be restricted to be affine. Then we have the fibered category $(S\to \mathbb A^1)\mapsto \mathcal C_S$, and *then* you can start to think about an inverse image functor induced by a map $T\to S$ of affines over $\mathbb A^1$. Note that your attempt is about trying to construct a fiber functor, or the forgetful functor, from $\mathcal C_S$ to $\mathrm{Aff}/\mathbb A^1$, which is not the same as the inverse image functor.

Comment: Thank you dear @KevinCarlson, I see that I've been confusing inverse image functor with the forgetful functor. If I understand you well, inverse image functor for fibered category over $\operatorname{Aff}/\Bbb A^1 $ is concerned about pulling back along morphisms $T \to S$ in $\operatorname{Aff}/\Bbb A^1$, that's why you first consider the category $\operatorname{Aff}/S $. When you say that $\mathcal C_S$ is the fiber of the fibered category over $S$, do you mean the fiber over $\operatorname{Aff}/S$?

Comment: Another question: would it be a problem considering only morphisms in $\operatorname{Aff}/\Bbb A^1 $ with codomain $S$?

Comment: No-a fibered category over $\mathrm{Aff}/\mathbb A^1$ has fibers over each object of $\mathrm{Aff}/\mathbb A^1$, such as $S\to \mathbb A^1$. The map $T\to S$ is meant to be an arbitrary morphism over $\mathbb A^1$, as with the understanding I indicated in my answer, the scheme $S$ is not fixed in this framework.